# JS code working on my page but does not on fiddle, why?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a piece of little code that is working on my site but it'is not working on fiddle, why? I have turned on  - no wrap - in body. It's a little button that should toggle, and it's toggling on page but not on fiddle.

```
    function details(){
  reg.classList.toggle("reg");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hubkubas/4pLp8sb0/26/

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: `reg` is `undefined` which means you either didn't include the lib it uses or you declared it on your side but not on the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4pLp8sb0/31/

Comment: Your function is ok but the problem with reference object reg.Please check reg is null or not

Comment: Are you sure that on your site the element `.reg` does not also have an id of reg. That would make your code work since ids create a corresponding global variable in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code. http://jsfiddle.net/4pLp8sb0/37/

there is no var defined for reg. you could try below one to get reference. this would be there in your codebase that is why it would be  working

```
 var reg = document.querySelector('.reg');
```

**Update:**

If you want text also to be modified like "More Details" or "Less Details"
refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/4pLp8sb0/41/

Answer (score 2):

The variable is possibly declared on your side but you forgot to do it in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pLp8sb0/31/

```
var reg = document.getElementsByClassName('reg')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like following

```
function details(){
  var reg = document.querySelector('.reg');
  reg.classList.toggle("reg");
}
```

I guess you are missing selector part